# How to create a pivot table in R with multiple rows and one column

Tags: r, pivot-table

Hey guys I am trying to build a pivot table in R which I just started using. I know this topic has been discussed a few times here but I can't find an example that would help me out. I have data table which looks like following
[image]

What I am trying to do is build a triangle with Years as columns. Country & City as rows. So it looks like this

[image]

I have tried using group_by but can't figure it out. Would really appreciate any advice I can get!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Combination of `group_by()` and `pivot_wider()` would probably work.

Comment: `pivot_wider(df, c(Country, City), names_from = Year, values_from=Sales)`

Comment: Note that Excel's "summarize value field by" corresponds to the *values_fn* argument to `pivot_wider`. Example: `pivot_wider(..., values_fn = sum)`.